# Use single transaction for multiple sqlcommand execution when some commands might raise exception

Tags: c#, sql-server, transactions

I am trying to use a transaction to execute multiple SqlCommands within a single connection. I am using an example from the following link  [Use Batching in Sql to improve performance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-use-batching-to-improve-performance) with only one modification being, I have added try/catch for each `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` .

I don't want to abort the transaction if any command fails and want to handle it in application side. And want to commit changes in the end.

But when we get exception during above call, Transaction object is disposed and I am getting invalid operation exception because of this when trying to commit in the end. Any pointers on how to commit the transaction even if some of the commands failed, would be very helpful.

Following is the snippet I am using.

```
 using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("Sql.ConnectionString")))
{
   conn.Open();
   SqlTransaction transaction = conn.BeginTransaction();

   foreach (string commandString in dbOperations)
   {
      SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(commandString, conn, transaction);
      try{
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      }
      catch(Exception ex){
        //some exception handling. 
      }
   }

   transaction.Commit();
```

}

Comment: There is no purpose of using transaction here. Just remove the transaction it works as per your expectation.

Comment: Can you show us some examples of the commands you are batching together?

Comment: Hi @selvakumar, without the transaction, I am seeing a 3x performance hit.But if I use transaction and don't commit, I am not getting the exception but could see improvement in performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely the answer is not to group all the statements within a single transaction?

Or, if some should fail the whole transaction but some not then group the ones that should fail the whole transaction in a single transaction and run the other statements individually.

Are you entirely sure what the effects of using/not using transactions are?

Comment: Hi @spodger, I want to know if there's any way to combine successful command executions in a transaction ignoring the failed ones. Since in the stats provided in the link, I could see at least 8x times performance improvement with using Transaction.